# Linux SCSI Scan - is it still echo "- - -" in Linux 3.2

Tags: linux, scsi

I'm working with attaching new SCSI drives to a virtual host, and the current method in my team's work instructions is to rescan the SCSI bus with:

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan
```

However, this was written a few years back, and we've moved on to newer Linux 3.2 systems.  Is the method still `echo "- - -"`... so many things today in Linux are a bit nicer and less arcane... is there a new method I'm unaware or is this still how its done?

Comment: It's a virtual machine? This depends a lot on the hypervisor, and you failed to mention it.

Comment: I'm not sure why the hypervisor is relevant, I'm working inside the Linux VM to rescan the SCSI bus.  But, for what it's worth, its VmWare.

Comment: Which _version_ of VMware? VMware is a _company_, not a product. And which drivers are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [Red Hat storage administration guide](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/scanning-storage-interconnects.html), the method you mentioned is there, along with some other options which you might prefer.

> echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/hosth/scan
>
> [...] This procedure will add LUNs, but not remove them.

There's also the less arcane [/usr/bin/rescan-scsi-bus.sh](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/rescan-scsi-bus.html), which has the advantage that it can also remove devices.

The same `/sys/class/scsi_host/` tree is still there in 3.2, so there's still nothing preventing one from scanning for new devices using that method.